# How to have a color square in a text caption

Tags: color, legend

[image]

Just like the figure on the right hand.
The small squares in green color.

Comment: Something like in this question:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201300/inline-boxes-alternative-to-pifonts-non-filled-but-shadowed-box, although not directly connected to captions

Comment: Since the above represents a legend, just use a graphics package like tikz.  The only tricky part will be aligning the centers of the text and square.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple way with the `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{black}{green}{\rule{0pt}{6pt}\rule{6pt}{0pt}}\quad Text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]