# Boxes with black borders

Tags: symbols, color, tcolorbox

I am here referring to an old post: [Inline boxes: alternative to pifont's non-filled-but-shadowed box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201300/inline-boxes-alternative-to-pifonts-non-filled-but-shadowed-box/201304#201304)

For all the boxes, how can I define a black border?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

% some color definitions
\definecolor{cblue}{RGB}{16,78,139}
\definecolor{cred}{RGB}{139,37,0}
\definecolor{cgreen}{RGB}{0,139,0} 

% normal box
\newcommand{\sqboxs}{1.2ex}% the square size
\newcommand{\sqboxf}{0.6pt}% the border in \sqboxEmpty
\newcommand{\sqbox}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{\sqboxs}{\sqboxs}}}
% empty box
\newcommand{\sqboxEmpty}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{\sqboxf}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \textcolor{#1}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\sqboxs}\rule{\sqboxs}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
I like these.
\sqbox{cred}  \sqbox{cgreen} \sqbox{cblue}

And also these.
\sqboxEmpty{cred}  \sqboxEmpty{cgreen}  \sqboxEmpty{cblue}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another `\fbox` to your boxes.

For the first one

```
\newcommand{\sqboxblack}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\sqbox{#1}}}
```

and for the second

```
\newcommand{\sqboxEmptyblack}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\sqboxEmpty{#1}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

% some color definitions
\definecolor{cblue}{RGB}{16,78,139}
\definecolor{cred}{RGB}{139,37,0}
\definecolor{cgreen}{RGB}{0,139,0}

% normal box
\newcommand{\sqboxs}{1.2ex}% the square size
\newcommand{\sqboxf}{0.6pt}% the border in \sqboxEmpty
\newcommand{\sqbox}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{\sqboxs}{\sqboxs}}}
\newcommand{\sqboxblack}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\sqbox{#1}}}

% empty box
\newcommand{\sqboxEmpty}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{\sqboxf}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \textcolor{#1}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\sqboxs}\rule{\sqboxs}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\sqboxEmptyblack}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\sqboxEmpty{#1}}}

\begin{document}
I like these.
\sqbox{cred}  \sqbox{cgreen} \sqbox{cblue} \sqbox{black}

And these.
\sqboxblack{cred}  \sqboxblack{cgreen} \sqboxblack{cblue} \sqboxblack{black}

And also these.
\sqboxEmpty{cred}  \sqboxEmpty{cgreen}  \sqboxEmpty{cblue} \sqboxEmpty{black}

And these?
\sqboxEmptyblack{cred}  \sqboxEmptyblack{cgreen}  \sqboxEmptyblack{cblue} \sqboxEmptyblack{black}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Continuing on the previous question, how can I do the same now with other shapes like circles, triangles, and rotated squares?

Comment: @abhishek Please open a new question for this....

Comment: Done...thanks for help with the previous one.