# error on adding item list in sidecaption using memoir

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, captions, memoir

I try to add an item legend using tikz [drawed bullet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201300/inline-boxes-alternative-to-pifonts-non-filled-but-shadowed-box) in sidecaption with memoir, using Texlive 2013 updated, and xelatex, to this working MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amstext}    % defines the \text command, needed here
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}

\newsubfloat{figure}{}
\newsubfloat{table}{}

\captiontitlefont{\normalfont}% title font
\precaption{\raggedright}% for Caption N
\captiondelim{\newline}% newline*
\captionstyle{\raggedright}% for title
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\onelineskip}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\renewcommand*{\sidecapstyle}{%
 \ifscapmargleft
    \captionstyle{\justifying\scriptsize}%
  \else
    \captionstyle{\justifying\scriptsize}%
  \fi}

% BOX LEGEND 
% some color definitions
\definecolor{tangoBlue1}{RGB}{114,159,207}
\definecolor{tangoOrange1}{RGB}{245,121,0}
\definecolor{tangoRed1}{RGB}{239,41,41}

% normal box
\newcommand{\sqbox}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline={(a.base)}]
     \fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (1.2ex,1.2ex);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
        \item \sqbox{tangoBlue1} indique une valeur $v$ minimale, 
        \item \sqbox{tangoRed1} une valeur $v$ maximale, et 
        \item \sqbox{tangoOrange1} les autres valeurs $v$ intermédiaires 
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{}[fig:xyspacePspaceOmultimodal]
     \centering
      \subbottom[]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_xyespaceSolutionCandidate:a}}
     \subbottom[bla]{
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_xyespaceSolutionCandidate:b}}\hspace{1em}
     \subbottom[bla]{
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_sxyespaceSolutionCandidate:c}}
    \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When i try to move the item code into sidecaption, like this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{\begin{itemize}
        \item \sqbox{tangoBlue1} indique une valeur $v$ minimale, 
        \item \sqbox{tangoRed1} une valeur $v$ maximale, et 
        \item \sqbox{tangoOrange1} les autres valeurs $v$ intermédiaires 
\end{itemize}}[fig:xyspacePspaceOmultimodal]
     \centering
      \subbottom[]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_xyespaceSolutionCandidate:a}}
     \subbottom[bla]{
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_xyespaceSolutionCandidate:b}}\hspace{1em}
     \subbottom[bla]{
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_sxyespaceSolutionCandidate:c}}
    \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}
```

I have this error

> ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros ABD: EverySelectfont
>   initializing macros   
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.112 ^^I\end{sidecaption}
> ```

Comment: I get no errors or warnings using TeX Live 2014.

Comment: Hum, so my problem is with xelatex and texlive 2013 recently updated. I try to download the 2014 version. Thanks for information.

Comment: BTW: often the fact that you are using `xelatex` would be worth a mention. Just tested, and luckily it does not make a difference in this case.

Comment: Don't understand, my texlive is updated to 2014, error persist, i update my message with my code modified which produce error :( My xelatex version is XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014)

Comment: Wait a minute, I only tested the first item, not the extra stuff to be added (that is why you are always asked to post full minimal examples not sniplets. Will test the extra data

Comment: I get the same, error, will investigate.

Comment: You cannot get stuff like that into a caption, or it will be quite hard. You cannot do that with a normal caption either, not sure why.

Comment: ok, perhaps i can replace with an array, one line one dot ?

Comment: Why is that data not written on the figure instead?

Comment: If the solution of itemize in sidecaption is impossible i study this question :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `sidecaption` tries to typeset the text inside an `\mbox` (`\hbox` in TeXnical terms), where `itemize` is illegal. Wrap it in a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amstext}    % defines the \text command, needed here
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}

\newsubfloat{figure}{}
\newsubfloat{table}{}

\captiontitlefont{\normalfont}% title font
\precaption{\raggedright}% for Caption N
\captiondelim{\newline}% newline*
\captionstyle{\raggedright}% for title
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\onelineskip}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\renewcommand*{\sidecapstyle}{%
 \ifscapmargleft
    \captionstyle{\justifying\scriptsize}%
  \else
    \captionstyle{\justifying\scriptsize}%
  \fi}

% BOX LEGEND 
% some color definitions
\definecolor{tangoBlue1}{RGB}{114,159,207}
\definecolor{tangoOrange1}{RGB}{245,121,0}
\definecolor{tangoRed1}{RGB}{239,41,41}

% normal box
\newcommand{\sqbox}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline={(a.base)}]
     \fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (1.2ex,1.2ex);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{%
\parbox{\marginparwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
        \item \sqbox{tangoBlue1} indique une valeur $v$ minimale, 
        \item \sqbox{tangoRed1} une valeur $v$ maximale, et 
        \item \sqbox{tangoOrange1} les autres valeurs $v$ intermédiaires 
\end{itemize}}}[fig:xyspacePspaceOmultimodal]
     \centering
      \subbottom[]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_xyespaceSolutionCandidate:a}}
     \subbottom[bla]{
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_xyespaceSolutionCandidate:b}}\hspace{1em}
     \subbottom[bla]{
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{subfig_sxyespaceSolutionCandidate:c}}
    \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's odd, I did test `minipage` and it failed. Now I tested again and it works....

Comment: @daleif With `minipage` the spacing is wrong.

Comment: @egreg, why? I thought `minipage` and `\parbox` was more or less interchangeable.

Comment: @daleif In `minipage` LaTeX sets `\@minipagetrue` which has some consequences on lists.

Comment: @egreg, does that mean that in general the memoir code ought to be using `\parbox` internally instead of `minipage` to encapsulate the sidecaption?

Comment: @daleif I guess so, but I don't know the details; surely doing `\setbox\something=\hbox{<caption>}` for measuring and then `\unhbox\something` doesn't allow paragraph breaks in the caption.

Comment: That it not what memoir does anyway. It would be nice to figure out a method to generally allow lists and `center` in those sidecaptions

Comment: @daleif A `minipage` seems the best tool.

Comment: Hmm, then probably something else is at play. Will look at it later. It cannot handle selevral paragraphs either. Presumably because several of the macros involved are not long.